# How can I see my drupal site as a anonymous user while logged in as admin?

Tags: users, debugging

I want to use Devel Themer to look at the "homepage" comment field, but it only shows up for anonymous users.

Is there anyway to see a page as a anonymous user would, and at the same time be logged in as an admin so that I can use the Devel Themer module?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No that is impossible.

What you could do is give access to devel for all users. You shouldn't be using devel in a live environment anyways, so just make sure you remove devel and revoke permissions before staging to production environment.

Comment: Brilliant. The site is hosted on my VirtualBox so no concern there. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The way I do this is simply have a different browser open with the site open as anonymous - Logged in on Firefox, anonymous on Chrome, for example.

EDIT
Whoops, I didn't fully understand the question on that quick read - hmm. Devel should have a tool that you can 'switch user' - at least I know there is a module for it. I wonder if 'anonymous' is one of those users?

Comment: Right, you can switch user with devel, but then you would have anonymous permissions. Googletrop had it right, give anonymous users 'access developer information' permission and it will give anonymous users access to devel themer.

Answer (score 0):

It says it's buggy, but you could try the https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade module, which allows you to view a site as a different user.